# ios - UIStackView and multiline UILabels

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to put multiline `UILabels` into the vertical `UIStackView` and then put this `UIStackView` into the horizontal `UIStackView` alongside other views (`UIImage` and `UIButton`).

My problem is that number of lines of the label is always one. Is it possible to force the label become multiline without specifying the width of the vertical stack?

Want to implement something like this:
[image]

Comment: "Is it possible?" As long as the layout engine can determine the width of the vertical stack unambiguously, sure it is! Please add more details about the _actual_ problem that you are having. Add a [mcve] at the very least.

Comment: Have you set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` on the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can do that...

[image]

"Outer" horizontal stack view:

[image]

"Inner" vertical stack view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to force the label become multiline without specifying the width of the vertical stack?

No , the base behind wrapping is a specified width (static/proportional) , so you should either set a width for the vertical stack or the label

Comment: If the _horizontal stack view_'s distribution were set to fill equally, surely that would allow the vertical stack view to have an unambiguous width (assuming no other constraints), without actually _specifying_ a width for it?

Comment: yes as fill equally works for height with vertical stack so width is still un-known hence, no wrapping

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what you are trying to achieve. But from what I understand, when vertical stack view is embedded again in the horizontal stack View. The horizontal stackView property along with its constraints determine how to set up the position specially stackView alignment and distribution.Even inside the stack view you can set your label to width to be of maximum constant. As I am not sure of the exact scenario, maybe you could simply add a line break \n to your UILabel text.